# Magento2 multipart emails with text/html and text/plain

Tags: magento2, email

Magento2 sents multipart emails but the message only has text/html MIME parts, the text(plain) part is missing. So email clients which can/may not display html will show nothing and spamfilters like SpamAssassin will complain about MIME_HTML_ONLY.

Is there a way to bring Magento2 to send proper multipart emails? Can the text/plain part be generated automatically from the html version of the email?

Answer (score 1):

I searched the same think because I had a warning from a mail-tester solution. I just found this solution for Magento 1 from Amasty : https://git.amasty.com/mm/email (see page 38 https://www.slideshare.net/meetmagento/andrei-vashkievich-5-steps-for-nospam-emails-in-magento).

So I think it could be done for Magento 2 but I'm not good enough to do it ... If someone hear about something like this for Magento 2, please tag me !